# MS Visual Web Developer 2010 Express

Tags: visual-web-developer-2010

I have installed MS Visual Web Developer 2010 Express and created the dll and also add the strong name to it.

Now I want to installed the dll into GAC. When i searched the file system i did not find gacutil.exe. Therefore i used regasm.exe .

Now im getting RegAsm: warning RA0000:No types were registered.

Suggest how we can install the same. Also for your information im using windows 7

Comment: Got a solution for this issue i.e. Installation of Windows SDK which will have gacutil.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a solution for this issue i.e. Installation of Windows SDK which will have gacutil.exe